# Calling an VB-function in a .NET Core project generates errors

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-core

I have a .NET Core project and want to call a old VB-function. I extended the reference in my C# project and in Visual Studio seems to be everything OK (no errors) and I can see the VB-class and I can use the function. But if I start the project and use it in my controller I get this error:

> Message=Method not found: 'Int32 Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Len(System.String)'

What does that mean and how can I solve this? The old VB class use global variables (unfortunately) and is complex so converting is difficult.

I've tried to make a new VB Class shell (without global variables) which use the other class but same error. If I use the VB project lonely it works.

Comment: The very fact that you call `Len(String)` instead of String.Length is a bug.  You shouldn't be using this method to begin with.  .NET Core got rid of a lot of cruft and unnecessary legacy methods.

Comment: *Why* are you using this method? If you want to avoid null exceptions, you should a) check that you actually got valid data, b) use `?.`, eg `myPossiblyNullString?.Length` will return 0 or c) replace nulls with String.Empty, eg `var myVariable=myPossiblyNullString??String.Empty;`. Len may allow you to avoid an exception but doesn't mean your program won't fail in other interesting ways

Comment: The VB Code is really really old (a PC1 crypt class from year 2000) and not my code. What I'am wonder is that this VB-code works lonely. But you are right - change to .lenght fix that error. Now is the next error - there is used a old mid-function wich I have to change too I'am afraid. New error ist:
System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'System.String Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Mid(System.String, Int32, Int32)'.'

Thanks for your quick help!

Comment: .substring fix the old mid(), now the next error, jesus

'Method not found: 'Int32 Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Asc(System.String)'.'

Comment: ASC ist change to int(), but now I got this error:

System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Conversion' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, 

How can I solve this?

Comment: There's still a lot of documentation around for the old VB functions. Basically, what you need to do, and it's **long** overdue is to ensure you understand what the old function does and then locate a suitable replacement for it within the .NET Framework. It's not a productive use of anyone's time for you to just reach each stumbling point and add it as yet another comment on here and expect others to go and search the documentation for you.

Comment: Ok understand. Excuse me. I wanted to use the old VB solution only with me without much customization in the C # project.

Comment: Because I don't understand the crazy, complex and old VB cypher code I build a standalone console app with this VB code and call this from my c# app and get the PC1 text back. Not really nice but seems to work for now.

Comment: The discussion here might be useful to you.  https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/29873